# 'Grover' object has no attribute 'run'

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

Trying to do an application of Grover's algorithm. I am referring to Qiskit's video on the satisfiability problem however aqua does not exist so I am trying some work arounds.

```
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem  
from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle 

log_expr = '((A & B) | (B & C)) & ~ (B & D)'
algorithm = Grover(PhaseOracle(log_expr))

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = algorithm.run(backend)
```

and get:

```
      1 backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
----> 2 result = algorithm.run(backend)

AttributeError: 'Grover' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
algorithm = Grover(PhaseOracle(log_expr))
```

with

```
problem = AmplificationProblem(PhaseOracle(log_expr))
```

And

```
result = algorithm.run(backend)
```

with

```
grover = Grover(quantum_instance=backend)
result = grover.amplify(problem)
```

Note, however, that it is recommended to use Qiskit primitives to run the algorithms instead of dealing with backends directly (see [here](https://medium.com/qiskit/introducing-qiskit-algorithms-with-qiskit-runtime-primitives-d89703ecfca3)). So, for your code to be future-proof use [`Sampler`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/primitives.html#overview-of-sampler) primitive instead of `QuantumInstance`

```
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem  
from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle 

log_expr = '((A & B) | (B & C)) & ~ (B & D)'

problem = AmplificationProblem(PhaseOracle(log_expr))

sampler = Sampler()
grover = Grover(sampler=sampler)
result = grover.amplify(problem)
```

Comment: There are also a couple of tutorials for Grover here https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials.html#algorithms that use a Sampler primitive (in this case the reference one from Terra).

Comment: neither of the above worked. I assume you mean 'result = grover.amplify(algorithm)' not problem? Even so, I get ' 'Grover' object has no attribute 'oracle' '

Comment: Sorry, I tested the code on my machine, but forgot to copy one line while writing the answer. I added the missing line now.

Comment: hmm this makes it not callable for when I want to see the histogram: 'plot_histogram(result('measurement'), title = "Possible combos", bar_labels = True)'   returns ''GroverResult' object is not callable'

Comment: Use `result.circuit_results` instead of `result('measurement')`

Comment: awesome. Thank you. I'll take your advice and start learning about Sampler :)